# want to animate view only once when the screen is open. and stop animation when user touch screen

Tags: android, android-animation

animate tram

```
if (tram != null && pagePosition == 0 ){
    final Animation animation1=new TranslateAnimation(-100f, 80.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    animation1.setDuration(3000);
    animation1.setRepeatCount(0);
    tram.startAnimation(animation1);
    animation1.setFillAfter(true);

    animation1.setRepeatMode(0);
}
```

when translate slide to next slide i want to stop animation.
it repeat animation whenever translate slide

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out:

```
  public class CustomTranslateAnimation extends TranslateAnimation {

    public CustomTranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta,
                                    float toYDelta) {
        super(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
    }

    private long mElapsedAtPause = 0;
    private boolean mPaused = false;

    @Override
    public boolean getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation) {
        if (mPaused && mElapsedAtPause == 0) {
            mElapsedAtPause = currentTime - getStartTime();
        }
        if (mPaused)
            setStartTime(currentTime - mElapsedAtPause);
        return super.getTransformation(currentTime, outTransformation);
    }

    public void pause() {
        mElapsedAtPause = 0;
        mPaused = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        mPaused = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: just want to stop animation when translate to next slide